# Making an entire row in GridView a link?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a entire GridView row a link and I think I got it but I'm running into an issue. As you can see from below, all my query strings data is coming from the DB now i want to add a query string that is not coming from the DB, how could I accomplish this??

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {           

        string Types = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();
        string Rounds = Request.QueryString["Rounds"].ToString();
        string Groups = Request.QueryString["Groups"].ToString();

        string Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id").ToString();
        string League = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "League").ToString();
        string Team1 = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Team1").ToString();
        string Team2 = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Team2").ToString();
        string Type = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TType").ToString();
        string Location = ResolveUrl("Update_Match.aspx" + "?Id=" + Id + "&Team1=" + Team1 + "&Team2=" + Team2 + "&League=" + League + "&Type=" + Type + "&Types=" + Types + "&Rounds=" + Rounds + "&Groups=" + Groups);
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = string.Format("javascript:window.location='{0}';", Location);
        e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it coming from then?

Comment: Just to clarify...it sounds like you answered the question posed in the title and you are actually asking how to obfuscate a querystring instead?  If so, you might want to change the title.

Comment: @James, this is something that i want to hard code in the link. It's not coming from the DB, for example Id and League come from the table fields and Type, Rounds and Groups is being pull from the QueryString from the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote this a bit to try to understand your questions better.  It's more verbose than you might want, but it will make it clearer.  All you need to do is build a querystring from a number of elements, some of which come from your database, some from your prior page, and others may be hardcoded.  That's all simple.  Just assign each variable in the querystring its value first, then build the string.

For example, suppose you are grabbing the team name from the database using the ID like this:

```
String Team1 = db.Teams.Where(w => w.TeamID = TeamID).First().TeamName;
```

and you are setting the Type as a hardcoded value:

```
Int type = 0;
```

When you are done building your variables, just put them together like this:

```
string QS = "Id=" + ID.ToString();
QS = QS + "&Team1=" + Team1;
QS = QS + "&Team2=" + Team2;
QS = QS + "&League=" + League;
QS = QS + "&Type=" + Type.ToString();
QS = QS + "&Types=" + Types;
QS = QS + "&Rounds=" + Rounds.ToString();
QS = QS + "&Groups=" & Groups.ToString();
e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='newpage.aspx?" + sQueryString;
e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
```

It doesn't matter how you acquire each value as long as they are converted into strings to build the querystring.  Is there something more I'm missing?

Comment: Sure, as you can see some fields in the link come from the table in the DB but I also need to add some data to the link that is not coming from the DB. Type, Rounds and Groups are values carried from the previous page. This link looks like this: ?Types=L&Rounds=0&Groups=6 Now i want to take this and added to the RowDataBound and I want it to look like this: ?Id=36&Team1=USA&Team2=England&League=None&Type=2&Types=L&Rounds=0&Groups=6 I hope this makes sence

Comment: I'm not sure if you are missing something or I am.  You can build a querystring from any number of string values acquired any way you like.  I adjusted my answer to better illustrate it but if there is something more you need, please try to articulate it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your code should work.  Do you get any script errors when you try to load the page?
Also, what browser are you testing this with?

I would try making the "c" in onClick lowercase to start with.

In addition to that, I would consider revising your code a bit because it appears as though you would be vulnerable to a cross site scripting attack because you are not cleaning the QueryString before putting it in the attribute.

An attacker could exploit this by modifying the queryString of the page to say:

```
http://www.yourpage.com/index.aspx?otherQueryString=3&Groups=<script>window.alert("Hello XSS!!");</script>
```

Comment: -1 This gives a lot of general advice, but does not answer the question at all.